# Как сделать массовую переустановку компьютеров сразу?

Tags: установка

Как сделать массовую переустановку компьютеров сразу? У меня компьютерный зал не охота по одному переустанавливать

Comment: Уточните, какую ОС собираетесь устанавливать - от этого может зависеть ответ

Answer (score 2):

Можно установить и настроить один, потом сделать образ диска и клонировать его через сеть на другие компьютеры при помощи:

1. Norton Ghost (не знаю в каком продукте Symantec он сейчас спрятан)
2. [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) (свободно распространяемое ПО)

Вот еще инструменты: (сам не использовал, но функционал вроде похож)

3. [Paragon DriveCopy](http://www.paragon.ru/home/dc-professional/)
4. [Acronis Snap Deploy](http://www.acronis.com/ru-ru/business/enterprise-solutions/image-deployment/)

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но разве начиная с висты при этом не полетит лицензия на остальных?

Comment: @Qwertiy Не ошибаетесь. Начиная с Windows XP потребуется активация. Только в вопросе про ОС вообще ни слова

Comment: Вроде для xp ещё нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну как нет. Если она "видит" совсем не такое железо, на котором активирована, требует реактивацию. У меня 200 компов в организации. Когда меняешь винчестеры между системниками (чтобы быстрее сотрудника пересадить, если системник совсем не в сознании) почти наверняка активация слетает (хотя изредка и не слетает)